# Apply conditional aggregation on a pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with the following data

```
date       type       value
1/1/2016   a          1
1/1/2016   b          2
1/1/2016   a          1
1/1/2016   b          4
1/2/2016   a          1
1/2/2016   b          1
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create conditional aggregators after grouping by date, to perform an operation both across the entire day as well as for a particular type, with output as below

```
date       sum_value    avg_value    a_sum     a_max    b_sum    b_max
1/1/2016   8            2            2         1        6        4     
1/2/2016   2            1            1         1        1        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle this in 2 steps. The first step is the get `mean` and `sum` through a `df.groupby` call on `date` only.

```
x = df.groupby('date').value.agg(['mean', 'sum'])
print(x)

          mean  sum
date               
1/1/2016     2    8
1/2/2016     1    2
```

The next 4 columns need a groupby on `date` and `type` followed by an unstacking.

```
y = df.groupby(['date', 'type']).value.agg(['sum', 'max']).unstack()
y.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in x.columns.values] # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878539/4909087
print(y)

          sum_a  sum_b  max_a  max_b
date                                
1/1/2016      2      6      1      4
1/2/2016      1      1      1      1
```

Now, concatenate `x` and `y`.

```
res = pd.concat([x, y], 1).reset_index()
print(res) 
       date  mean  sum  sum_a  sum_b  max_a  max_b
0  1/1/2016     2    8      2      6      1      4
1  1/2/2016     1    2      1      1      1      1
```

Comment: unstacking, that's the part I was missing, thank you!!!!! that's what happens when you skim a quarter of the way through the pandas docs I guess lol.