# Merge MultiIndex columns together into 1 level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Here's some data from another question:

```
date       type       value
1/1/2016   a          1
1/1/2016   b          2
1/1/2016   a          1
1/1/2016   b          4
1/2/2016   a          1
1/2/2016   b          1
```

Run this line of code:

```
x = df.groupby(['date', 'type']).value.agg(['sum', 'max']).unstack()
```

`x` should look like this:

```
         sum    max   
type       a  b   a  b
date                  
1/1/2016   2  6   1  4
1/2/2016   1  1   1  1
```

I want to combine the columns on the upper and lower level to get this:

```
           sum_a  sum_b   max_a  max_b
date                  
1/1/2016   2       6        1       4
1/2/2016   1       1        1       1
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's discussion of this here:

[Python Pandas - How to flatten a hierarchical index in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/python-pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns)

And the consensus seems to be:

```
x.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in x.columns.values]
print(x)
          sum_a  sum_b  max_a  max_b
date                                
1/1/2016      2      6      1      4
1/2/2016      1      1      1      1
```

Would be nice if there was an inbuilt method for this, but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the least headache version.

Comment: I kinda feel that this question is a dupe now of the linked question, should we mark as dupe?

Comment: @EdChum Yeah, I already came across that, but it was so verbose that my eyes glazed over it. I think this would be good in that it's a much simpler formulation of the same problem. I leave it to you, resident pandas gold badge :)

Comment: I'll think I'll dupe hammer this then, note that in your case the `strip` is superfluous

Answer (score 2):

Very similar solution to the above using zip:

```
x.columns = [x + '_' + i for x, i in zip(x.columns.get_level_values(0), x.columns.get_level_values(1))]
x
          sum_a  sum_b  max_a  max_b
date                                
1/1/2016      2      6      1      4
1/2/2016      1      1      1      1
```